# Linear dependence for positive coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

From my textbook:
[image]

Essentially, they are making the following claim:

For all $b$, exists $k \geq 0$ s.t. $F k = b$ for some matrix $F$ iff there exists $k > 0$ s.t. $Fk = 0$.

This seems similar to the idea that, if a system $F$ is linearly independent, then $F$ has only a single solution to $Fx = 0$.

Anyway, how do we prove the above statement with $k \geq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$\forall b\, \exists k\geq 0(Fk=b)$ **implies** $\exists k>0 (Fk=0)$**:**

Assume $F \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times j}$ and for every $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $k \in [0,\infty)^j$ such that $Fk = b$.

Let $k_1 = (1,1,\ldots,1)$. There is some $k_2 \in [0,\infty)^j$ such that $F k_2 = -F k_1$, since $-F k_1$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then let $k = k_1+k_2$. Every coordinate of $k$ is at least $1$, and so is positive. And

$$ F(k_1 + k_2) = F k_1 + F k_2 = F k_1 - F k_1 = 0 $$

$\exists k>0(Fk = 0)$ **implies** $\forall b \exists k\geq 0\, (Fk=b)$**:**

Assume $F \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times j}$ with $j \geq n$ is full-rank, $\ell = (\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_j) \in (0,\infty)^j$, and $F\ell=0$. Let $b$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $F$ is full-rank, there is some vector $a = (a_1, \ldots, a_j) \in \mathbb{R}^j$ so that $Fa = b$, but it could have negative coordinates. Define $m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}^j$ by

$$ \begin{align*} m &= \max_{1 \leq i \leq j}\left(-\frac{a_i}{\ell_i}\right) \\
k &= a + m\ell
\end{align*}$$

(The division is defined since $\ell_i>0$.) The $i$-th coordinate of $k$ is

$$a_i + m \ell_i \geq a_i + \left(-\frac{a_i}{\ell_i}\right) \ell_i = 0 $$

So $k \in [0,\infty)^j$, and

$$ Fk = F(a+m \ell) = F a + m F\ell = b + m \cdot 0 = b $$